# How to remove ImageButton's padding programmatically?

Tags: android, widget

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image);
button = new ImageButton(this);
button.setImageBitmap(image);
```

I want to remove padding between image and border of button.
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you simply want an image that you can click? Maybe an ImageView with an OnClickListener is what you want.

Comment: Right. But if removing padding of ImageButton is not easy, I will use ImageView.

Comment: you can use ***android:scaletype="fitxy"*** of imagebutton in xml.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`setPadding()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to try to remove the space between the image and the border.

```
button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Otherwise I suggest using a regular `ImageView` with an `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Its working on API Level 22, but nothing happens on API Level 19 KK.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image)
        imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: oh. i think i missed your comment