# How do I remove the white padding around my imagebutton?

Tags: android, android-imageview, imagebutton

My app looks like this:

[image]

I want my two image buttons to completely fill the space of my linearlayout, the way the Checkbox does - none of that white padding around them. I tried so many things suggested on stackoverflow = making the background "@null" and so on, but none of them worked.

I suppose I could try an ImageView, but I want to have that 'click' effect.

Any ideas? Here's my code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView_2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:background="#d9d9d9">
    </EditText>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffa500"
        android:text="New CheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >
    </CheckBox>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set your ImageView backgrouund to transparent and set your color or drawable in src. Something like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="?colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Solved the above problem alright. But in fact I need to put an image on the imagebutton. I want the button to look like it has been pressed - I want the image to be the same but the background colour of the button to change. Looks like I need to use a selector.xml.

Comment: Yes. You can use a selector with some shape or layer-list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`setPadding()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to remove the space between the image and the border. This actually worked for me when making something similar in school.

[**Check out this answer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13434422/5908129)